# <button> works as a submit button by default when type not mentioned?

Tags: html

Does  element works as a submit button by default when type is not mentioned?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="export" value="preview">Preview</button>
```

When the button is clicked, the form is submitted and redirected to other page.

Comment: Make working example with form, we will be able to help faster.

Comment: Different browsers may use different default types for the <button> element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default value of a (input type=) submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592777/what-is-the-default-value-of-a-input-type-submit-button)

Answer (score 2):

To quote my first google hit.

> Always specify the type attribute for the `<button>` element. Different
>   browsers may use different default types for the `<button>` element.

Answer (score 1):

> `type="submit"` is the default if the attribute is not specified for
>   buttons associated with a `<form>`, or if the attribute is an empty or
>   invalid value.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

However, it looks like some older IE versions use button as the default type (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629749/is-type-submit-the-default-for-a-button-in-a-form-in-ie8-through-11) for details).

Answer (score 0):

For the button to work as a submit button, you will need to have the type set, within the form tags.

```
<button type="submit"></button>w
```