# Is type="submit" the default for a button in a form in IE8 through 11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to figure out if it's worth specifying `type="submit"` for a button inside a form if I'm supporting more recent IE versions; as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) states, type="submit" is the default if the attribute is not specified for buttons associated with a `<form>`, or if the attribute is an empty or invalid value." However, [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_type.asp) states, "Always specify the type attribute for the button. The default type for Internet Explorer is "button", while in other browsers (and in the W3C specification) it is "submit"."

Based on what I've been able to find so far, it sounds it's only IE7 and below that have `button` as the default value for the `type` attribute; is that so?

Comment: Why not just do it? Its not like you'll have 12 trillion submit buttons in your project. Don't get to crazy about this, IE is going down anyways. https://www.w3counter.com/trends

Comment: Fair point, but generally I like to leave out things that are already the default. In any case it would be nice to know how to find the default attribute value for an IE version.

Comment: Looks like your guess is true: http://web.archive.org/web/20160417074456/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534696(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @NattyC well, now you can't anymore, because you know better :) thanks Ilya!

Comment: Nice sleuthing work Ilya!